# How to troubleshoot a hanging process in Windows?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, process

I've been having the same problem with several applications lately -- I start them and they just hang. I don't see anything on the screen, however the application is listed in Task Manager and its CPU usage is 0%.

Are there any utilities that can help me troubleshoot this? Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) should help you get started. You'll need to do a little ... exploring.

Comment: Process Monitor too.  Especially Process Monitor.  If the program opens files or network connections, you'll need to see if it hangs up on access.  Status to look for is "ACCESS DENIED".  If it opens a network socket, but you see no further activity, it's another.

CPU at 0% implies waiting on I/O.  Does the app "gray out" (not responding to Windows events)?

Answer (score 1):

Like Joseph said, Process Explorer is a good place to get started. The rest of the SysInternals suite is useful too.

Are the processes related in anyway? If they run separately do they work correctly? I'd go from running them individually, then running them together in some kind of methodical way to see which ones play nice and maybe it's one that's causing the problems.